# bind javascript function to options of <select>

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I want to do something like:

```
<select>
    <option> escapeXml("Black") </option>
    <option> doFunction("Brown") </option>
    <option> doOtherFunction("Red") </option>
</select>
```

How would I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: You'd listen for the change event on the select element, and then check the value of the selected option, and call the appropriate function

Comment: Let me Understand you wont to populate the selection field with options on load... with javascript ? or you wont to be able to call a different function for each option ? or both ?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is call a single javaScript function for onChange or onBlur. Get the selected value in that Js funtion.

Use if..else loop to call other functions based on the values.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a different function for each option...

...I would do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(select){
    var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    switch(value){
        case "Black": escapeXml("Black"); break;
        case "Brown": doFunction("Brown"); break;
        case "Red": doOtherFunction("Red"); break;
        default: return;
    }
}
</script>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(this)">
    <option value="Black"> Black </option>
    <option value="Brown"> Brown </option>
    <option value="Red"> Red </option>
</select>
```

You can call this on load :

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    myFunction(document.getElementById("mySelect"));
},false);
```